# Index future generated contracts using TheGraph

Tags: subgraph, thegraph, thegraph.com

I have an ethereum contract that is called:

```
tokenFactory.sol
```

This contract generates ERC20 tokens as it goes along, and when it does it emits and event that has the generated ERC20 address.

I would like to go and then index the `Transfer` event of these generated Token Contracts. Is there a way to do that programmatically with Subgraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll define this events and contracts and handlers under the `templates` key in the manifest. Which is as `dataSources` except there is no address and start block because they haven't been deploy yet.

When you receive an event that this contract has been deployed, or needs to be indexed, you will create it using the generated template

```
import { Token } from '../../generated/templates';

...
export function handleToken(event: TokenEvent): void {
  const tokenAddress = event.params.token;
  Token.create(tokenAddress);
...
}
```

[docs](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/developing/creating-a-subgraph/#data-source-templates)

Comment: yep thats how I did it about 5 months ago

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

If you want something simple, maybe checkout the OpenZepelling autogeneration code:
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/subgraphs/0.1.x/

also you can check this basic erc.20 subgraph
https://github.com/graphprotocol/erc20-subgraph